A problem about asymptotics behaviour of the sum
Let $A\subset N$ be a set of zero density and let $a_1$ be its smallest
element. Also, let $L:[a_1, +\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R_+$ be an increasing function which is continuous and differentiable on $[a_1, +\infty)$. Assume moreover that $L'(x) =O(1)$. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent:
(a) $$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=(1+o(1))x$$
(b) $$A(x)=(1+o(1))\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}$$
where $A(x)=\sum\limits_{a\le x,a\in A}1$ and density of $A$ is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{A(x)\over x}$.
This is the source of this problem. enter link description here
I have solved the (b)$\Rightarrow$(a) part, but I have no idea about the (a)$\Rightarrow$(b) part. And I wonder wether the density of A is nacessary for this problem.
Here is my proof of the first part. By abel summation,
$$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=L(x)A(x)-\int_{a_1}^xL'(x)A(x)dx.$$
Substituing $A(x)=(1+o(1))\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}$ in,
$$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=(1+o(1))(\int_{a_1}^{x}\frac{L(x)}{L(t)}d t-\int_{a_1}^xd t\int_{a_1}^t\frac{L'(t)}{L(u)}du)=(1+o(1))(\int_{a_1}^{x}\frac{L(x)}{L(t)}d t-\int_{a_1}^xdu\int_{u}^x\frac{L'(t)}{L(u)}d t)=(1+o(1))(\int_{a_1}^{x}\frac{L(x)}{L(t)}d t-\int_{a_1}^x\frac{L(x)-L(t)}{L(t)}d t)=(1+o(1))\int_{a_1}^xdt=(1+o(1))x.$$
